# PyCharm error: "Cannot set IntelliJ theme: null"

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

#### The problem

I'm trying to change my PyCharm color theme, but when I do, I get an error: `Cannot set IntelliJ theme: null`.

#### What I've tried

- I've restarted my computer.
- I've updated all my plugins.
- If I restart PyCharm, I *am* able to change the color theme without encountering the error.  So it seems like some change-of-state while I'm using the program is causing the error.

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after facing the issue and restarting IDE?

Comment: @y.bedrov https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/927884/idea.log

Comment: Thanks! Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248701. Should be fixed in 2020 version.

Comment: @y.bedrov Thank you so much!! I'm surprised I didn't come across that link while Googling the error message.  If you want to add that as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it.